# Tomcat 8.5 server.xml - Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [_default_]. Host names must be unique

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to change server.xml with Tomcat 8.5 and get the following error when trying to start tomcat:

09-Feb-2017 06:23:25.278 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (135, 20) : Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [*default*]. Host names must be unique.

Relevant server.xml code:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" >
  <SSLHostConfig>       
                  keystoreFile="/saswork/sasadmin/tomcat/certs/eccerts" 
                   keystorePass="xxxxxxxx"
                   storepass="xxxxxxxx"
                   truststoreFile="/saswork/sasadmin/tomcat/certs/eccerts"
                   sslProtocol="TLS"
 </SSLHostConfig>
```

Advice appreciated on what the error means and suggestions on a solution welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your syntax is incorrect for `<SSLHostConfig>`.
It should be:

```
<SSLHostConfig>       
    <Certificate ... />
 </SSLHostConfig>
```

Also, I've had much better luck putting `keystorePass` inside of `<Connector>`.

The only `<Connector>` that works without failing for me is:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
     maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
     keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keyAlias="alias"
     keystorePass="password"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Otherwise these `MultipleSSLHostConfig` element errors occur.

Comment: Thanks v much.  I had tried the <Connector> approach initially but was getting errors so ventured down the <SSLHostConfig> route.

Based on your feedback I tweaked my <Connector> to replicate yours and all is working now.

Comment: By using clientAuth="false" you were accidentally creating a default SSL host config in addition to the one you explicitly declared. This made 2, hence the error. See @muttonUp's excellent answer below.

Answer (score 48):

A quite confusing error "**Multiple SSLHostConfig elements**" when you clearly only have one.

Turns out this is caused by using deprecated directives.

If you put any of these [deprecated attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_NIO_and_NIO2_(deprecated)) in the `Connector` directive, tomcat assumes you are using the old way and auto creates a `SSLHostConfig` itself, which then conflicts with the one you are creating.

In your particular case you were using `clientAuth="false"` on the `Connector` directive which has become `certificateVerification="none"` on the `SSLHostConfig` directive

Comment: I had the very same problem when using, now deprecated, attribute sslProtocol="TLS"

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The accepted answer above uses now long-deprecated configuration parameters.

Comment: @eppesuig as you indicated that sslProtocol is deprecated what is new correct attribute

Comment: @AdinduStevens, the new attribute of `SSLHostConfig` is `protocols`.

Answer (score 1):

Following sample will definitely work for JKS keystore in Tomcat 8.5:

```
    <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
        port="443" maxThreads="200"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    compression="on" compressionMinSize="1048576"
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/json,application/javascript"
    defaultSSLHostConfigName="*.host.com"      >

<SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1"
        ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
        hostName="*.host.com" >
    <Certificate
        certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
            certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks"
            certificateKeystorePassword="changeit" type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Comment: only jks? non jks?

Comment: See examples on the [Apache Tomcat page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my configure that works:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           defaultSSLHostConfigName="your.hostname.com">
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="your.hostname.com" protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore"
                     type="RSA" certificateKeystorePassword="xxx"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I had to set the `defaultSSLHostConfigName` attribute of the connector and the `hostName` attribute of the SSLHostConfig.