# Multiple HTTPS Connectors in Tomcat using different certificates

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I am currently using a Tomcat 8.5 to host a web application via HTTPs. The connector configuration looks as follows:

```
<Connector 
    port="8443"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
    connectionTimeout="10000" 
    maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="myKeystore"
    keystorePass="changeit"
/>
```

What I'm trying to do now is to host the application under another URL with another cerficate, ideally from the same keystore.

As far as I undestood from the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) I need to add second connector. My problem is that I'm not sure how to tell the connector which certificate to use in the keystore.

It seems the way to go is related to using the keyAlias attribute. However, this seems to have been deprecated in favour of SSLHostConfig. Unfortunately, I failed to find the right kind of documentation for my use case for either way of configuring, let alone examples.

How do I configure the connectors properly? If there are multiple way, what would be considered best practise? Should I even store both certs in the same keystore?

Comment: What is the reason for not using a separate connector _and_ separate keystore?

Comment: Personal preference I guess, to have everything in one place/file. It's not strictly necessary, but I felt it should be possible. After all a keystore is be design meant to (or at a minumum capable of) storing several keys, not just one.

Comment: Good point.  It looks like you have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding a page detailing all the Connector and [SSLHostConfig attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig) in the Tomcat documentation I managed to create a working setup.

The two connectors now look like this:

```
<Connector 
    address="192.168.0.100"
    port="8443"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
    maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" connectionTimeout="10000" 
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">
    <SSLHostConfig
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            certificateVerification="false">
        <Certificate 
            certificateKeystoreFile="myKeystore"
            certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
            certificateKeyAlias="server1cert"
            certificateKeyPassword="server1pw"
        />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

<Connector 
    address="192.168.0.101"
    port="8443"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" maxThreads="150" 
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">
    <SSLHostConfig
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            certificateVerification="false">
        <Certificate 
            certificateKeystoreFile="myKeystore"
            certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
            certificateKeyAlias="server2cert"
            certificateKeyPassword="server2pw"
        />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Something to watch out for is to replace *all* deprecated SSL attributes in the Connector. 
Otherwise Tomcat will internally create a default SSLHostConfig based on the deprecated attributes resulting in an error during startup. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496152/3696510) for more information.